# Checking the convergency of the following series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I wanted to determine when the sum $\sum n^{n^{1/3}}x^{2n}$ converges/diverges. I noticed that the series diverges when $x \leq -1$, $x \geq 1$, but I don't know that to do to check for convergency when $-1<x<1$. I tried to apply the ratio test and the root test, but I wasn't able to get anything out of it

Answer (score 1):

If $|x|<1$, then\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|n^{n^{1/3}}x^{2n}\right|}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{n^{1/3}/n}|x|^2\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{n^{-2/3}}|x|^2\\&=|x|^2\\&<1,\end{align}and therefore the series converges, by the root test. Note that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{n^{-2/3}}=1$$because, for each $x>0$,$$x^{x^{-2/3}}=\exp\left(x^{-2/3}\log(x)\right)=\exp\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x^{2/3}}\right)$$and that, by L'Hopital's Rule,$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x^{2/3}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{-1}}{\frac23x^{-1/3}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac32x^{-2/3}=0.$$

Comment: You're so right! Thanks

Comment: $n^{n^{-\frac 23}}\neq (\sqrt[n]{n})^{-\frac 23}=n^{-\frac 2{3n}}$

Comment: @zwim I've edited my answer. Thank you.